# MenuItems hovering

Tags: dojo

Could somebody explain me how to customize Menu and MenuItems?
I wish that hovering did not disappear if cursor is not over the widget. I mean that MenuItem must be selected and hovered after clicking on it. And it must be stay selected and hovered till we clicked another item.
This is an: [example](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/checkout/dijit/tests/test_Menu.html) but I can't figure out how it works.

Little update:
I'm sorry for my english. Probably I poorly explained the problem.
Look at the [example](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/menus/demo/simpleDeclarativeMenu.php)
when I click on any menuItem it does not stay selected (I mean if mouse cursor is over another button then selection disappears).
And now look at the
[example](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/checkout/dijit/tests/test_Menu.html)
when I click on button "comedy" or "drama" or "romance" or etc its stay selected. Even if mouse cursor is not over the clicked button.
That's what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear:

"*hovering did not disappear if cursor is not over the widget. I mean that MenuItem must be selected and hovered after clicking on it. And it must be stay selected and hovered till we clicked another item.* "

"hovering did not disappear if cursor is not over the widget." is correct for all Menu and menuItems, but all popup Menu will disappear after you click on it. From the menu test page you mentioned, I didn't see any popup menu will keep at there after you make a selection click.

But if your are looking something like passivePopupDelay features, that's dojo1.9 new added features. Please see here for [dojo 1.9 release note](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/releasenotes/1.9)

**Also, there's a new passivePopupDelay property on MenuBars (and also Menus) that, when set to a finite value, merely hovering the menu will open the dropdown. Usually the user needs to click the menu to show the drop down menu. **

**EDIT:** based on updated question, here are some info from [document](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/Menu.html)

*“Selected/active” is in the sense of the selected tab, and is controlled by the mouse or keyboard. Implementation-wise, it means that either the MenuItem has focus, or focus is on a submenu of that MenuItem.
**The Menu/MenuBar domNode has a dijitMenuPassive/dijitMenuActive class so that CSS rules for hover can be customized based on whether or not the menu has focus. Once the menu gets focus the dijitMenuHover effect is disabled in favor of the dijitMenuSelected effect**, so that the dijitMenuHover effect won’t linger on “File” if user moved the mouse over “File” but then used the keyboard arrows to move to the “Edit” MenuBarItem. (This is a setting in tundra/nihilo/soria and can be changed if desired.)*

You may follow this to compare your code with the source code of [dojo menu test page](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/checkout/dijit/tests/test_Menu.html).

Comment: I'm sorry for my english. Probably I poorly explained the problem.
Look at the example http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/menus/demo/simpleDeclarativeMenu.php
when I click on any menuItem it does not stay selected (I mean if mouse cursor is over another button then selection disappears).

And now look at the example
http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/checkout/dijit/tests/test_Menu.html
when I click on button "comedy" or "drama" or "romance" or etc its stay selected. Even if mouse cursor is not over the clicked button.
That's what I want to achieve, but do not know how

Comment: Ok, now I understand your question. You may have a look at source code of test_menus.html, here are some information mightbe help: [dijit/Menu](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/Menu.html) , please pay attention to the last paragraph.

Comment: Its not working anyway. Menu from example http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/menus/demo/simpleDeclarativeMenu.php and example http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/checkout/dijit/tests/test_Menu.html have same class 'dijitMenuPassive' but different behavior